# Node.js message.split returns undefined

Tags: node.js, twitch

So I want to create a bot command that when i type 
`-say Something Here` it returns `someone says: Something here` But all it does is returns `someone says: undefined` Btw i'm using `tmi.js`

```js
bot.on("chat", function (channel, user, message, self) {
  if(message === "-say")
    var code = message.split('  ')[1];
    bot.action("stankotomic", "someone says: " + code);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure, but i think you meant something else. Tell me if i got you wrong. but as I've understood your question, that is the correct way to do it.

*considering that message = "-say Something Here";
and your result should be: "Someone says: Something Here"*

Lets look at your code line by line:

```
if(message === "-say") // I am 100% sure "-say" and 
//"-say something here" are different. correct me if i am wrong.
//so we need to check for the first word, or first element in our array of words. 
//lets first create array than check: if(message.split(" ")[0] == "-say")

var code = message.split('  ')[1]; //now, we don't have 2 spaces together 
//anywhere in our message, so array == nothing. 
//I guess it should be more like: message.split(" ").shift().join(" ");
// this will return you: "Something Here".

bot.action("stankotomic", "someone says: " + code);
```

Your final code:

```
bot.on("chat", function (channel, user, message, self) {
if(message.split(" ")[0] == "-say")
      var code = message.split(" ").shift().join(" ");
      bot.action("stankotomic", "someone says: " + code);
});
```

PS:

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) documentation.

[Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) documentation.

[Shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the following line:

`var code = message.split('  ')[1];`

...and change it to the following, it should help:

`var code = message.split(' ')[1];`

You had two spaces as the separator argument to `split()` where you should have only had one.

See here for documentation for [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)